# Синтаксическая ошибка в строке обновления записи таблицы БД

Tags: php, mysql

```
UPDATE klient SET (n_srok_v = '$_POST['n_srok_v']', n_1_1='$_POST['n_1_1']' ) WHERE xxx==1;
```

xxx - автоинкремент

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE `klient` SET n_srok_v = '$_POST['n_srok_v']', n_1_1='$_POST['n_1_1']'  WHERE xxx=1;
```

Знак равенства "="
А вообще рекомендую использовать плейсхолдеры, чтобы не было `$_POST['n_srok_v']` вот таких вещей в запросе. Во-первых, это небезопасно, скорее всего вы сейчас таким запросом дыру для активного *XSS* делаете, а во-вторых плохо читаемо.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE klient SET n_srok_v = '.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['n_srok_v']).', n_1_1='.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['n_1_1']).' WHERE xxx=1;
```

Можно так к примеру:)
А по факту [[@karbachinsky](/users/3616/karbachinsky)](/users/3616/karbachinsky) прав, данные передаваемые пост/гетом лучше проверять, чтобы потом не было мучительно больно.

Конкретно этот запрос:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE klient SET n_srok_v = ".$_POST["n_srok_v"].", n_1_1 = ".$_POST["n_1_1"]." WHERE xxx=1");
```

Чтобы быстро находить ошибки, еще в процессе написания, юзай редакторы, могу посоветовать phpdesinger платная, 30 дней бесплатные. ключ можно купить или не очень))

Comment: Не забываем, что если ковычки поставишь mysql_query('бла бла бла'); то  " меняешь на '
ЗЫ: клиент не строковой параметр а название таблицы. в данном случае его брать в `name` не стоит)) а то ругаться будет на неправильные ковычки опять таки.

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE klient SET n_srok_v = '$_POST["n_srok_v"]', n_1_1='$_POST["n_1_1"]' WHERE xxx=1;`
Внимание на кавычки и одиночный знак равенства. Да, и при вставке этого запроса в php, вам придется какие-то из кавычек экранировать.

Comment: все равно выдает ошибку
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in Z:\home\prokat.by\www\function\update.php on line 11

Comment: Можно посмотреть ваши строки 10 и 11? Либо на 10 не хватает точки с запятой, либо вы-таки не заэкранировали кавычки в запросе.

Comment: <?
include_once "mysql_conect.php";
include_once "select.php";
$aa=$_POST['xxx1'];
$aa1=$_POST['n_srok_v'];
$aa2=$_POST['n_1_1'];
echo $aa2;


UPDATE klient SET (n_srok_v = '$aa1', n_1_1='$aa2') WHERE xxx=$aa;
//echo "обновлено";
?>
и такое сообщение
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in Z:\home\prokat.by\www\function\update.php on line 10



Comment: Все ясно. Гуглите тему использования mysql в связке с php и читайте [доки][1].

[1]:http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php

Answer (score 1):

Еще такой возможен вариант:

```
UPDATE klient SET n_srok_v = '{$_POST['n_srok_v']}', n_1_1='{$_POST['n_1_1']}' WHERE xxx=1;
```

Желательно обработать еще входные данные.

Answer (score 0):

Можно такой вариант попробовать.

```
$n_srok_v = $_POST['n_srok_v'];  
$n_1_1 = $_POST['n_1_1'];
$sql = "UPDATE klient SET n_srok_v = '" . $n_srok_v . "', n_1_1 = '" . $n_1_1 . "' WHERE xxx=1";
```

Comment: $query="UPDATE $table SET n_srok_v='$aa1',n_1_1='$aa2',n_1='$aa6',n_x1='$aa3' WHERE xxx=$aa"; 

mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$query); 
нашел такое решение, работает